# How does two continuous equal in JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript

Basically, the line of code `curr = curr[ch] = curr[ch] || {}` sets variable `ch` as key of the object and set `{}` as the value of the object, then point to its child reference.

But can someone explain in detail how it works? Thanks

http://jsbin.com/gokapoc/1/edit?js,console

```
let root = {};
let curr = root;

let ch = 'a';
curr = curr[ch] = curr[ch] || {};
ch = 'b';
curr = curr[ch] = curr[ch] || {};
ch = 'c';
curr = curr[ch] = curr[ch] || {};

console.log(root);
```

It will show the result:

> ```
> {
>   a: {
>     b: {
>       c: {}
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Assignment operator is right associative, and the `||` has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table), so rewrite the lines like this: `curr = (curr[ch] = (curr[ch] || {}));` and it should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s do a walk through. I added parentheses to make things more clear – they don’t change the meaning.

```
let root = {};
let curr = root;
```

Nothing difficult until now

```
let ch = 'a';
curr = (curr[ch] = (curr[ch] || {}));
```

Okay, so `curr[ch]` is `undefined` at the moment because there’s no property `a` (`ch`’s value at the moment) in `curr` which points to the same object as `root`. Therefore the most inner parentheses evaluates to `{}`.

This value is assigned to `curr[ch]`. So obviously there’s a property `a` in the `root` object now.

Finally, this object (`root.a`) is assigned to `curr`, because the assignment in the outer parentheses returns the assigned value, which is the object at property `a`.

```
ch = 'b';
curr = (curr[ch] = (curr[ch] || {}));
```

Basically the same as before, just important to note that `curr` is not `root` here but the same object to which `root.a` points. In the end `curr` will point to the same object as `root.a.b`.

```
ch = 'c';
curr = (curr[ch] = (curr[ch] || {}));
```

Yeah, and this should be clear by now.

Very compact but not very clear code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! Very clear explanation!